# Is this path planning problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Given N integers L1, L2, ... , Ln  ,we have a robot that starts at (0,0) moves north on integer grid for L1 steps, then it either continues in its current direction or makes 90 degrees right turn then moves L2 steps and repeats for all Li.

Problem: Can the robot return to the origin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following "DOUBLE-PARTITION" problem: given a set of $m$ positive integers $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m\}$, can you partition $X$ into four sets $A,B,C,D$ such that $\sum_{a \in A} a = \sum_{b \in B} b$ and $\sum_{c \in C} c = \sum_{d \in D} d$?

There is a Karp reduction between DOUBLE-PARTITION and your problem: choose $n=4m$ and set $L_i = 0$ if $i$ is not a multiple of $4$ and $L_i = x_{i/4}$ otherwise. Essentially, for every non-zero length $L_i$, the robot can freely choose whether to travel $L_i$ units north, south, east, or west. The sets $A,B,C$, and $D$ corresponds to the lengths of the movements along each of these directions.

Then you only need to show a Karp reduction between some NP-Hard problem and DOUBLE-PARTITION. You can use the classical PARTITION problem: given a set of positive integers $Y$, can you partition $Y$ into two sets $W,Z$ such that $\sum_{w \in W} w= \sum_{z \in Z} z$?

Consider the instance of DOUBLE-PARTITION where $X=Y$. If $A,B,C,D$ is a valid partition for this instance then $W = A \cup C$ and $Z = B \cup D$ is a valid partition for the PARTITION instance.
Conversely, if $W,Z$ is a valid partition for the PARTITION instance, then $A=W$, $B=Z$, $C=D=\emptyset$ is a valid partition for the DOUBLE-PARTITION instance.